# Filter .json data with jquery according to input values

Tags: jquery, json, filter

I need to build up a Flight search engine and the data is stored on a .json file.I have a form, When user select four fields[From, to and two dates (start an return)] and press submit, I need to return the results with the above criteria. How can I do this. Please help.